# How to Set Updated Base Price with Shipping Charges in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, shipping-methods, checkout-page

I am currently using Magento 2.4

When I click on "Buy Now". At that Popup occurs and Another Add-ons asking. After I select Add-ons. I updated price using below code :

```
  $newCalcualtionPrice = $baseprice+$addonstotal;
  $product->setPrice($newCalcualtionPrice);
```

After that I can see my updated price in View Cart page. Then I will click on "Process to Checkout".Also On Step 1. "Shipping Information " I am able to see updated Cart Value.

But When I am select Shipping method. Like Fixed Charges. And Click on "NEXT". Then Review & payment step. I am not able to get updated Cart Value. I am getting "Original Product Price + Shipping Charges". But... I want "Updated Cart Value + Shipping Charges" . So Can anyone help me how to do it ?

```
public function execute()
    {
        $results = ['error' => '', 'success' => '', 'url' => '', 'content' => '', 'minicart' => ''];
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $results['error'] = __('Your session has expired');
            return $this->jsonResponse($results);
        }

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        //print_r($params); exit;

        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
                    )->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }
            $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                $results['error'] = __('No product added.');
                return $this->jsonResponse($results);
            }

            if(!empty($params['addonsproduct'])){
                $baseprice = $product->getPrice();
                $addonstotal = array_sum($params['addonsproduct']);
                $newCalcualtionPrice = $baseprice+$addonstotal;
                $product->setPrice($newCalcualtionPrice);
            }
              
            if(empty($params['addonsproduct'])){
                $baseprice = $product->getPrice();
            }

            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $this->cart->save();

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );
            $success = '';
            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $success = __(
                        'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                        $product->getName() . $product->getFinalPrice()
                    );
                }
            }
            $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);
            $this->_coreRegistry->register('quote_item', $item);
            $this->_coreRegistry->register('product', $product);
            $this->_coreRegistry->register('current_product', $product);

            $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
            $update = $layout->getUpdate();
            $update->load('ajaxsuite_addcart_success');
            $layout->generateXml();
            $layout->generateElements();
            $results['success'] = $layout->getOutput();
            return $this->jsonResponse($results);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                    $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }
            $results['error'] = $e->getMessage();

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);

            if (!$url) {
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($this->getCartUrl());
            }
            $results['url'] = $url;
            return $this->jsonResponse($results);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $results['error'] = __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.');
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
        }
        return $this->jsonResponse($results);
    }
```

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried?

Comment: $newCalcualtionPrice = $baseprice+$addonstotal;
  $product->setPrice($newCalcualtionPrice);

Using this 2 lines Price is updated into database. Database table name : quote,quote_item

Comment: Please share the full code. Can not understand what you have  trying from this two line

Comment: I shared code above. The file path is : 
/var/www/projectname/app/code/themename/AjaxSuite/Controller/Cart/Add.php